# Building unirest request without maven

Tags: java, unirest

I'm been trying to learn unirest and apparently, I'm stuck with the situation of learning how to compile it without using maven. Below is what I've learned so far since most of the tutorials I've found is teaching unirest with maven. I'm not sure what else I missed but this is what I got so far:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class MainMethod {
    public static void main (String argsp[]) throws UnirestException {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5bc4373c300000b8097587bd")
                .header("accept", "applicaiton/json").queryString("apiKey","123")
                .asJson();

        System.out.println(jsonResponse.getBody());
    }
}
```

Each time I try to run the source code, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest

I'm just trying to create a simple request just to learn the basics of unirest but I'm not doing any good so far.

Did I forgot to do something? Any suggestion will be welcomed. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
This is the source code of the tutorial that I am following:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnStatusOkay() {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse 
      = Unirest.get("http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a9ce37b3100004f00ab5154")
      .header("accept", "application/json").queryString("apiKey", "123")
      .asJson();

    assertNotNull(jsonResponse.getBody());
    assertEquals(200, jsonResponse.getStatus());
}
```

Since the tutorial is using a method named `assertNotNull` and `assertEquals` which I can't figure out what they are, I simply replaced it with a print in hopes that I'll see how it responds.

Also, I'm using this site as a mock web service I think. I don't if its useful to the problem but here it is:

https://www.mocky.io/

**The whole error message I'm receiving:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at MainMethod.main(MainMethod.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add all dependencies unirest uses to your project as direct dependencies.
Take a look at the unirest dependency tree here:
[image: Dependency Tree Unirest]

Comment: I added all the mentioned libraries to my project but I still got the same error. I'll edit my post with something I think may help in figuring this out. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: which version of httpcore are you using? (the mentioned classnotfound: org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback is part of httpcore) you have to make sure that it's at least 4.4.4 !

Comment: I just tried both 4.2.3 and 4.3.3. I'll try using 4.4.4. I'll get back with you with the results. Thanks for the help. I'm really clueless with this.

Comment: Well that did something. The error changed into: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager**

Comment: Now you are missing httpclient:4.5.2 - you have to use exactly the versions which you can see in the picture for ALL of the dependencies

Comment: I see. I didn't pay attention to the versions. I'll try to find them and keep you posted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added all the versions and included the **httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar**. Its not returning any errors but its not returning anything at all. Anyway, I think I can make it work from here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You miss `httpcore-4.2.3.jar`in your classpath. addd it and the error will be solved

Comment: hi, i just added the said jar, unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: @Uzi what means *it didn't resolve the issue* exactly teh same exception?

Comment: @Uzi BTW Why you want use maven?

Comment: I mean the same error message occurred after I ran the code. I assume you meant why I "won't" use maven. Well the case is I'm trying to do the basic stuff just to see if I can make it work when I'm about it to create an additional package to our already enormous project. The project source code utilizes soap, rest and the like, and this is the first time that we need to use Unirest. I am not sure how will I do it if I have to add another package with maven.

Answer (score -1):

Add dependency in you pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

after running `mvn install` command your problem will be solved.

or without Maven

download a jar file of httpcore from [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10) and add into your class path.

Comment: Yes sorry, I can't. Thank you for the help though.